# I want to obtain following list in text instead of objects using twitter api in ruby programming language

Tags: ruby, api, methods, twitter, rubygems

I'd love to obtain following list in text (screen names) instead of objects using Twitter Api.  I am new to Ruby programming language and this's my first attempt using api with ruby especially Twitter api. What I expect is list of screen names instead of objects and I will show you examples bellow:

Results I get currently:
[current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUtJk.png)

[Desired and expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsobE.png)

I've tried methods such as .full_text and .text appended to the objects and didn't get my desired results.I've searched almost everywhere especially here in Stackoverflow and didn't find my answer yet.

This's my code below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'twitter'
require 'json'
require 'yaml'


client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = ""
  config.consumer_secret     = ""
  config.access_token        = ""
  config.access_token_secret = ""
end


following_list = client.friends('User-exmaple')
begin
  for friend in following_list
    puts friend
  end
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
  # NOTE: Your process could go to sleep for up to 15 minutes but if you
  # retry any sooner, it will almost certainly fail with the same exception.
  sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in + 1
  retry
end
```

I hope this explains everything, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by appending screen_name method to friend, example below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'twitter'
require 'json'
require 'yaml'


client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = ""
  config.consumer_secret     = ""
  config.access_token        = ""
  config.access_token_secret = ""
end


following_list = client.friends('User-exmaple')
begin
  for friend in following_list
    puts friend.screen_name
  end
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
  # NOTE: Your process could go to sleep for up to 15 minutes but if you
  # retry any sooner, it will almost certainly fail with the same exception.
  sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in + 1
  retry
end
```

I hope this explains the solution I found.

Comment: If it is working, you can set your answer as the solution.